# how can i combine multiple union in single query

Tags: mysql, select, union

The query return the avg bill of weekdays sitewise and also timing wise.
 The following query uses multiple union i want to combine all in single query
    how can i do this .

```
select 
        a.Month,
        'Weekday' as Type,
        'Lunch' as 'Sale',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '102' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '102',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '103' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '103',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '104' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '104',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '105' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '105',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '106' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '106'
    from
        (select 
            date_format(o.dayStatus, '%M') as Month,
                c.companyId as CompanyId,
                o.companyId as siteId,
                o.bill,
                round((sum(o.bill) / count(orderId)), 2) as AvgBill,
                date_format(DTTM, '%a') as Day
        from
            orders o, mdm_sites s, mdm_company c
        where
            s.siteId = o.companyId
                and o.isBilled = 1
                and billMode = 0
                and s.companyid = c.CompanyId
                and time(DTTM) <= '15:00'
                and date_format(DTTM, '%a') not in ('Sat' , 'Sun')
                and year(o.dayStatus) = (2014)
                and case
                when 0 in (1) then c.companyId in (c.companyid)
                else c.companyId in (1)
            end
                and case
                when 0 in (0) then o.companyId in (o.companyId)
                else o.companyId in (0)
            end
                and case
                when 0 in (12) then month(o.dayStatus) in (month(o.dayStatus))
                else month(o.dayStatus) in (12)
            end
        group by c.companyId , o.companyId) as a
    group by a.CompanyId 
    union (select 
        a.Month,
        'Weekday' as Type,
        'Evening' as 'Sale',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '102' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '102',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '103' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '103',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '104' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '104',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '105' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '105',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '106' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '106'
    from
        (select 
            date_format(o.daystatus, '%M') as Month,
                c.companyId as CompanyId,
                o.companyId as siteId,
                o.bill,
                round((sum(o.bill) / count(orderId)), 2) as AvgBill,
                date_format(DTTM, '%a') as Day
        from
            orders o, mdm_sites s, mdm_company c
        where
            s.siteId = o.companyId
                and o.isBilled = 1
                and billMode = 0
                and s.companyid = c.CompanyId
                and time(DTTM) > '15:00'
                and time(DTTM) < '19:00'
                and date_format(DTTM, '%a') not in ('Sat' , 'Sun')
                and year(o.dayStatus) = (2014)
                and case
                when 0 in (1) then c.companyId in (c.companyid)
                else c.companyId in (1)
            end
                and case
                when 0 in (0) then o.companyId in (o.companyId)
                else o.companyId in (0)
            end
                and case
                when 0 in (12) then month(o.dayStatus) in (month(o.dayStatus))
                else month(o.dayStatus) in (12)
            end
        group by c.companyId , o.companyId) as a
    group by a.CompanyId) union (select 
        a.Month,
        'Weekday' as Type,
        'Dinner' as 'Sale',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '102' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '102',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '103' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '103',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '104' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '104',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '105' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '105',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '106' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '106'
    from
        (select 
            date_format(o.dayStatus, '%M') as Month,
                c.companyId as CompanyId,
                o.companyId as siteId,
                o.bill,
                round((sum(o.bill) / count(orderId)), 2) as AvgBill,
                date_format(DTTM, '%a') as Day
        from
            orders o, mdm_sites s, mdm_company c
        where
            s.siteId = o.companyId
                and o.isBilled = 1
                and billMode = 0
                and s.companyid = c.CompanyId
                and time(DTTM) >= '19:00'
                and date_format(DTTM, '%a') not in ('Fri' , 'Sat', 'Sun')
                and year(o.dayStatus) = (2014)
                and case
                when 0 in (1) then c.companyId in (c.companyid)
                else c.companyId in (1)
            end
                and case
                when 0 in (0) then o.companyId in (o.companyId)
                else o.companyId in (0)
            end
                and case
                when 0 in (12) then month(o.dayStatus) in (month(o.dayStatus))
                else month(o.dayStatus) in (12)
            end
        group by c.companyId , o.companyId) as a
    group by a.CompanyId) union (select 
        a.Month,
        'Weekend' as Type,
        'Lunch' as 'Sale',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '102' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '102',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '103' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '103',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '104' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '104',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '105' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '105',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '106' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '106'
    from
        (select 
            date_format(o.daystatus, '%M') as Month,
                c.companyId as CompanyId,
                o.companyId as siteId,
                o.bill,
                round((sum(o.bill) / count(orderId)), 2) as AvgBill,
                date_format(DTTM, '%a') as Day
        from
            orders o, mdm_sites s, mdm_company c
        where
            s.siteId = o.companyId
                and o.isBilled = 1
                and billMode = 0
                and s.companyid = c.CompanyId
                and time(DTTM) <= '15:00'
                and date_format(DTTM, '%a') in ('Sat' , 'Sun')
                and year(o.dayStatus) = (2014)
                and case
                when 0 in (1) then c.companyId in (c.companyid)
                else c.companyId in (1)
            end
                and case
                when 0 in (0) then o.companyId in (o.companyId)
                else o.companyId in (0)
            end
                and case
                when 0 in (12) then month(o.dayStatus) in (month(o.dayStatus))
                else month(o.dayStatus) in (12)
            end
        group by c.companyId , o.companyId) as a
    group by a.CompanyId) union (select 
        a.Month,
        'Weekend' as Type,
        'Evening' as 'Sale',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '102' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '102',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '103' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '103',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '104' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '104',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '105' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '105',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '106' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '106'
    from
        (select 
            date_format(o.dayStatus, '%M') as Month,
                c.companyId as CompanyId,
                o.companyId as siteId,
                o.bill,
                round((sum(o.bill) / count(orderId)), 2) as AvgBill,
                date_format(DTTM, '%a') as Day
        from
            orders o, mdm_sites s, mdm_company c
        where
            s.siteId = o.companyId
                and o.isBilled = 1
                and billMode = 0
                and s.companyid = c.CompanyId
                and time(DTTM) > '15:00'
                and time(DTTM) < '19:00'
                and date_format(DTTM, '%a') in ('Sat' , 'Sun')
                and year(o.dayStatus) = (2014)
                and case
                when 0 in (1) then c.companyId in (c.companyid)
                else c.companyId in (1)
            end
                and case
                when 0 in (0) then o.companyId in (o.companyId)
                else o.companyId in (0)
            end
                and case
                when 0 in (12) then month(o.dayStatus) in (month(o.dayStatus))
                else month(o.dayStatus) in (12)
            end
        group by c.companyId , o.companyId) as a
    group by a.CompanyId) union (select 
        a.Month,
        'Weekend' as Type,
        'Dinner' as 'Sale',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '102' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '102',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '103' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '103',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '104' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '104',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '105' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '105',
        sum(case
            when a.siteId = '106' then a.AvgBill
            else '--'
        end) as '106'
    from
        (select 
            date_format(o.dayStatus, '%M') as Month,
                c.companyId as CompanyId,
                o.companyId as siteId,
                o.bill,
                round((sum(o.bill) / count(orderId)), 2) as AvgBill,
                date_format(DTTM, '%a') as Day
        from
            orders o, mdm_sites s, mdm_company c
        where
            s.siteId = o.companyId
                and o.isBilled = 1
                and billMode = 0
                and s.companyid = c.CompanyId
                and time(DTTM) >= '19:00'
                and date_format(DTTM, '%a') in ('Fri' , 'Sat', 'Sun')
                and year(o.dayStatus) = (2014)
                and case
                when 0 in (1) then c.companyId in (c.companyid)
                else c.companyId in (1)
            end
                and case
                when 0 in (0) then o.companyId in (o.companyId)
                else o.companyId in (0)
            end
                and case
                when 0 in (12) then month(o.dayStatus) in (month(o.dayStatus))
                else month(o.dayStatus) in (12)
            end
        group by c.companyId , o.companyId) as a
    group by a.CompanyId);


the output of above query

month       Type    Sale    102     103    104     105      106   
------------------------------------------------------------------
December    Weekday Lunch   566.63  530.19  644.9   556.9   467.65
December    Weekday Evening 433.89  404.69  457.18  547.22  396.6
December    Weekday Dinner  427.68  354.54  371.42  386.21  366.03
December    Weekend Lunch   410.57  381.36  383.86  365.94  394.14
December    Weekend Evening 418.45  305.31  429.12  464.81  301.9
December    Weekend Dinner  415.91  374.95  375.28  376.93  360.45
```

how can i do this in single query ,thanks

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of your query containing only the core problem? Otherwise I doubt anyone will go through that.

Comment: the query taking more time ....so  i want to execute in less time

Answer (score 0):

A pivot would be the ideal solution here and save on the Execution plan. Your Pivot groups would be Month, Type, Sale. Your calculation groups would be 102,103,104,105,106.

The pivot would all be done in a single query as well.

General guide for Pivots:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

An example that will be VERY similar to what you are trying to accomplish:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx